# Performing TCP/IP network I/O in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsstream

I'm writing a Swift application under OS X that needs to do TCP/IP port-level network I/O (optionally with SSL/TLS). I've done a lot of searching and it looks like NSStream is the way to go for this. However, the [class reference for NSStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/index.html) says that the class method `getStreamsToHost()` is deprecated as of OS X 10.10, which appears to be what I need to use, but doesn't say what replaces it. Does anyone know what mechanism I need to use in order to connect to a host on a specific port (no, not 80) in order to do the I/O in Swift under OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been replaced with `getStreamsToHostWithName`.

Example:

```
var input: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSInputStream?> = nil
var output: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSOutputStream?> = nil

NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(YOUR_HOST, port: YOUR_PORT, inputStream: input, outputStream: output)
```